# Batch file to edit and add line into ini file

Tags: batch-file, ini

I want to create a `.bat` file to push to more than 4000 users to edit lotus notes `ini` file, to disable the Instant Messenger.

I have to plug in this two lines `IM_DISABLE=1` & `IM_DISABLED=1`

If the lines exist, edit to the new value if it doesn't plug it in.

The ini file is called *notes.ini* residing in the path **C:\Users\PSuriya\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data**

However, this path should be generic to users.

Comment: Re: `If the lines exist edit to the new value if it doesn't plug it in.` Is the position of the lines critical, or can they be added onto the end of the file?

Comment: no the position is not critical and it could be added at the eof

Comment: It's nice that you've stated your requirements. Have you made any effort to fulfill them yourself (including researching previous questions about modifying text files from a batch file)? I see several previous questions in the Related list to the right of this question that should at least allow you to make an attempt at doing so.

Comment: Hi Ken, Yes i have tried other solution but they were not successful as it cleared the ini file and left only the characters i had intended to enter, some just wrote some character, it might be cos i dint get each line of it so id posted the question asking for a more straight forward approach. Thank for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - test it on some sample users

```
@echo off
set "file=%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\notes.ini"
if exist "%file%" (
   findstr /v /i "IM_DISABLE= IM_DISABLED=" "%file%" >"%file%.tmp"
   >>"%file%.tmp" echo/IM_DISABLE=1
   >>"%file%.tmp" echo/IM_DISABLED=1
   move /y "%file%.tmp" "%file%" >nul
 )
```

If the file doesn't exist then it will do nothing for that user.

Comment: Hi Foxi, Wow thank s alot buddy it totally worked this was exactly what i was looking for simple and readable code. my man..cheers buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a policy to push notes.ini settings to clients